# Как выбрать те числа из массива, которые лежат в заданом диапазоне?

Tags: java, массивы, числа

**Задача:**

Дан массив возрастающих чисел. Даны два числа. Написать метод, который из данного массива достанет ту часть, которая лежит между данными числами вкл.

**Моё решение:**

```
 public static int[] getSubArrayBetween(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    int k = 0;
    int[] result = new int[k];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] >= start && numbers[i] <= end) {
            result[k] = numbers[i];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Comment: `что я делаю не так?`  - забыли, что нужно делать с переменной k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде всё не так:

1. Создаётся пустой массив, так как `k == 0` в момент создания массива
2. Нестрогое сравнение индекса с длиной массива: `i <= numbers.length` вызовет выход за пределы массива `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` при обращении к элементам массива `numbers[i]`
3. Попытка обращения к элементам пустого массива `result[k]` также вызовет `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`
4. Индекс `k` не меняется, то есть все подходящие числа исходного массива пишутся в одну ячейку.

*Исправление указанных ошибок не является целью данного ответа.*

---

Самое простое/лаконичное решение -- с использованием Stream API, показанное в ответе Byb:

```java
public static int[] getSubArrayBetween(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    return IntStream.of(numbers).filter(n -> start <= n && n <= end).toArray();
}
```

Для более классического решения, без использования коллекций, следует найти минимальный и максимальный индексы элементов входного массива.  Если такие индексы не существуют, вернуть пустой массив, иначе копию массива между найденными индексами при помощи [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-):

```java
public static int[] getSubArrayBetween(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    if (numbers == null || numbers.length == 0 || numbers[0] > end || numbers[numbers.length - 1] < start) {
        return new int[0];
    }
    int min = 0;
    while (numbers[min] < start) min++;
    int max = arr.length - 1;
    while (numbers[max] > end) max--;
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(numbers, min, max + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как мы заранее не знаем, сколько чисел может лежать между заданными двумя числами `start` и `end`, то есть два варианта.

1. Использовать массив, но выделить заранее очень много памяти. Разумеется, такой подход очень плох, и поэтому его мы рассматривать не будем.
2. Использовать коллекции: они могут расширяться "на ходу", таким образом, сколько чисел будет лежать между `start` и `end`, - ровно столько мы и добавим.

Ниже приведён вариант, как можно исправить ваш код, используя коллекции.

```
public static List<Integer> getSubArrayBetween(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer integer : numbers) {
        if (integer >= start && integer <= end) {
            integers.add(integer);
        }
    }
    return integers;
}
```

Чтобы вернуть именно массив, код можно изменить так:

```
public static Integer[] getSubArrayBetween(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer integer : numbers) {
        if (integer >= start && integer <= end) {
            integers.add(integer);
        }
    }
    return integers.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```

Хотя в таком варианте возвращается массив оболочек `Integer`, а не примитивного типа данных `int`. Вернуть массив именно `int` можно, если использовать Stream API, с которым задача решается в целом проще (при условии, если все числа в массиве действительно идут по возрастанию).

```
public static int[] getSubArrayBetween(int[] numbers, int start, int end) {
    return IntStream.of(numbers)
            .filter(integer -> integer >= start && integer <= end)
            .toArray();
}
```